# Install sqldeveloper on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sqldeveloper

I am trying to install **SQL Developer** on **Ubuntu 16.04.** I have followed some tutorials but none of them worked. So I am asking you if you know how to install SQL Developer.

Comment: Follow this tutorial:- https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu/ It worked for me. Dont forget to update the java location on your first run of sqldeveloper.